# multiprocessing и Selenium chromedriver как подружить

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, selenium, google-chrome

Хочу отпарсить сайт в несколько окон Хрома через селеинум. Но многопочтоность не отработывает.

Код вида:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def browser_start(profile):
    #Принимает профиль хрома
    #Запускает хром через хромдрайв
    #Возвращает запущенный Хром тип объекта <class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>

def pasing_web(browser):
    #Принимает запущенную сессию хрома
    #Отработывает soors в BS с обходмами капчи и т.п., сохраняет в файл.

browser1=browser_start('profile_1')
browser2=browser_start('profile_2')

dataset=[browser1,browser2]

with Pool() as pool:
    result = pool.map(pasing_web,dataset)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Возникло исключение: AttributeError
Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'
```

В одно окно функции отработывают исправно, что-то методологически делаю неправльно, просьба подсказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function

В коде нужно было заменить импорт с этого:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

на это:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
```

В руководствах по многопоточности об этом не говориться.

Comment: Для мультипроцессинга все данные сериализуются и десериализуются, видимо, у селениума с этим какие-то проблемы. При мультитрединге ничего не надо сериализовать, но `GIL` может мешать одновременному выполнению потоков.